# I can't open an existing semaphore

Tags: c, linux, interprocess

I have defined as `#define SNAME "/mysem"` on my two programs.
On the first I am creating the semaphore as

```
sem_t *sem = sem_open(SNAME, O_CREAT, 0644, 1);
```

The second process is creating by the first and I am trying to open the existing semaphore as

```
sem_t *sem = sem_open(SNAME,0);
```

The two returning addresses are different though. Any help?

Comment: Post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There's no reason for the addresses to be the same. Two separate programs, two different virtual address spaces, etc. The pointer returned simply points to an opaque data structure. That structure is not shared by separate programs

Comment: It works, indeed... Thanks!

Comment: No worries, good luck!